# Resizing a f.text_area in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, textarea

How can I resize the `f.text_area` field in rails?

```
<%= f.text_area :message, :id => "message_area" %>
```

Neither `:cols => A, :rows => B` or `:size => "AxB"` work for some reason. Also I need the `:id` for styling.

Comment: How exactly does you code looks like (with :cols and :rows parameters)? How does the HTML output look like? What version of rails do you use? According to documentation, :cols and :rows should work: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area

Comment: The purpose of the first parameter `:message` is to give the text area an id, so the additional `:id` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: The purpose of :message is also to set the name and retrieve the value from the model instance and using :id is perfectly valid if you want to override the default id.

Comment: DanneManne is right, I mixed up the purposes of id an name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use CSS to style the textarea, just like this:

```
textarea#message_area {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

```
<%= f.text_area :message, :id => "message_area", :cols => 10, :rows => 10 %>
```

Just tested, this works in Rails 3 (and should work in Rails 2 as well).